# Prove a certain condition is satisfied by all non-abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I prove following problem in abstract algebra?

> Let $G$ is a finite non-abelian group. show that there exist elements $a,g,h\in G$ such that $g\neq h, h=aga^{-1}$ and $gh=hg$.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can g or h be trivial?

Comment: @ChrisK No, because if you apply $h=aga^{-1}$ you get $g=h$.

Comment: @JackM, true (g and h are otherwise g and h not unique)... stupid question, perhaps?

Comment: Do you know about source of problem?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: I think using [Conjugacy class equation](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_Class_Equation): $$\displaystyle \left|{G}\right| = \left|{Z \left({G}\right)}\right| + \sum_{x_j\notin Z(G)} \left[{G : C_G \left({x_j}\right)}\right]$$ is effective here.